# error C2073 и error C2512 в классе

Tags: c++

Имеется класс:

```
class Transport {
    public:
        Transport(int){
            //----- 
        }; 
        //-----  
};
```

Пишу так:

```
Transport a[3] = { Transport(1), Transport(2) };
```

Вот такие ошибки:

> error C2073: 'a' : elements of partially initialized array must have a default constructor
> error C2512: 'Transport' : no appropriate default constructor available

Что я делаю не так? Почему получаю ошибки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В массиве Вы объявили три элемента, а реально положили 2. Класс Transport не имеет конструктора по умолчанию, поэтому создать третий объект нельзя.

Что делать?

- создавать три объекта: `Transport a[3] = { Transport(1), Transport(2), Transport(3) };`
- создавать два объекта: `Transport a[2] = { Transport(1), Transport(2) };`
- объявить конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: Ещё вариант: не задавать размерность массива явно, она будет вычислена из фактического кол-ва элементов. `Transport a[] = { Transport(1), Transport(2) };` Ну, и учитывая неявность конструктора, можно писать проще: `Transport a[] = { 1, 2 };`.